# Is it possible to use a JSON object as a Google Cloud credential config param under Python?

Tags: python, json, node.js

I notice one can authenticate as a Google Cloud Client using the Python method

```
from_service_account_json(/path/to/credentials.json)
```

Like so:

```
 bigquery_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(
    'service_account.json')
```

However, I don't really want to keep the credentials file stored on the running instance. Rather, I just want to pass the JSON object, which I store as a JSON string in an environment variable.

The NodeJs version of the Google Cloud Credentials library allows for the JSON object to be passed like so:

```
const creds = JSON.parse(process.env.API_JSON);
const client = PubSub({
    projectId: projectId,
    credentials: creds
});
```

Is there a way to create the Google Cloud Credential in Python by passing the JSON string representing the credential information into a method such as, from_service_account_json()?

Answer (score -1):

http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html says that the default is to use the environment variables GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT if your code looks like the following:

> from google.cloud import bigquery
>
> client = bigquery.Client()

Comment: Thanks David. I've struggled to fully understand what the docs are trying to describe. Let me follow your most excellent suggestion,

Comment: Seems that the only assignment that to   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL that works is the path to the JSON file. When I try to use the JSON itself in the env var I get an authentication error, Let me keep at it.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry I can't help more. If it were me I'd write some code to create a file based on an environment variable at initialization. You can see someone asking to do the same thing for Go at https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/issues/185

Comment: I  got the questions asked on the GitHub issues repo for google auth library here:



https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/issues/225

It took a lot of back and forth to determine the solution. But, alls well that  ends well.